# Android RoomDB custom update query gives android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

When I try to run updateAlarmTriggered Query with two String parameters I get the following error:

**Logcat output**

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1299) abort at 33 in [UPDATE alarmTable SET triggered = 1 AND triggerTime = ? WHERE date = ?]: NOT NULL constraint failed: alarmTable.triggered

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: alarmTable.triggered (code 1299)
```

Here are my Dao and Entity classes:

**AlarmDao.java**

```
@Query("UPDATE alarmTable SET triggered = 1 AND triggerTime = :triggerTime WHERE date = :alarmDate")
    void updateAlarmTriggered(String alarmDate, String triggerTime);
```

**AlarmEntity.java**

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private String date;

@NonNull
private int triggered;

@Nullable
private String triggerTime;

@NonNull
public String getDate() {return date; }

public void setDate(@NonNull String date) {this.date = date; }

@NonNull
public int getTriggered() {return triggered; }

public void setTriggered(@NonNull int triggered) { this.triggered =triggered; }
```

I initalize the new entities with:

```
@Insert
    void insertAlarm(AlarmEntity alarmEntity);
```

And the alarmEntity object I:

```
 AlarmEntity newAlarm = new AlarmEntity();
 newAlarm.setDate(time.substring(4,20) + time.substring(30,34));
 newAlarm.setTriggered(0);
 newAlarm.setDeleted(0);
```

I can't figure out the reason why *NOT NULL constraint is failed on alarmTable.triggered*, because that's what I'm setting it to 1 at the updateQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update multiple columns use a comma `,` to separate columns. like following

```
@Query("UPDATE alarmTable SET triggered = 1, triggerTime = :triggerTime WHERE date = :alarmDate")
void updateAlarmTriggered(String alarmDate, String triggerTime);
```